# enabling email only if within specific location

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

I have created an app which i only want to work if the user is within a specific area (i.e. i only want the user to be able to sent an email if they are within a specific state of the country)

can some please either-

a) point me in the direction of a tutorial on how to set up a GPS boundary, and how to check if a user is within said GPS boundary

or

b) write an example for creating a GPS area, and how to check if the user is within the area.

i have the latitude and longitude of the user stored to variables.

here is my location manager code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longditute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and my email code:

```
-(IBAction)actionEmailComposer{

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        if ([witnessResponse  isEqual: @"Yes"]) {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
            mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailViewController setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dob in a Hoon Report(Y)"]];
            [mailViewController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Am I prepared to be called upon as a witness?: %@ \n Rego Number: %@ \n  Vehicle Make: %@ \n Vehicle Colour: %@ \n Vehicle Type: %@ \n Incident Date: %@ \n Incident Time: %@ \n Incident Location: %@ \n Do I know the Driver?: %@ \n Drivers Name (if Known) %@ \n Driver Gender: %@ \n Description of Incident: %@ \n Name of Person Reporting Incident: %@ \n Contact Number: %@ \n" , witnessResponse, regoNumber.text, vehilceMake.text, vehilceColour.text, vehicleType.text, incidentDate.text, incidentTime.text, location.text, driverKnownResponse, driverName.text, driverGenderResponse, additionalInfo.text, usersName.text, usersPhoneNumber.text] isHTML:NO];
            [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
            [mailViewController addAttachmentData:imageData  mimeType:@"image/jpg"   fileName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dob in a Hoon %@ , %@.jpg", Latitude,longditute]];
            [mailViewController setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        } else {

            MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
            mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailViewController setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dob in a Hoon Report(N)"]];
            [mailViewController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Am I prepared to be called upon as a witness?: %@ \n Rego Number: %@ \n  Vehicle Make: %@ \n Vehicle Colour: %@ \n Vehicle Type: %@ \n Incident Date: %@ \n Incident Time: %@ \n Incident Location: %@ \n Do I know the Driver?: %@ \n Drivers Name (if Known) %@ \n Driver Gender: %@ \n Description of Incident: %@ \n Name of Person Reporting Incident: %@ \n Contact Number: %@ \n" , witnessResponse, regoNumber.text, vehilceMake.text, vehilceColour.text, vehicleType.text, incidentDate.text, incidentTime.text, location.text, driverKnownResponse, driverName.text, driverGenderResponse, additionalInfo.text, usersName.text, usersPhoneNumber.text] isHTML:NO];
            [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
            [mailViewController addAttachmentData:imageData  mimeType:@"image/jpg"   fileName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dob in a Hoon %@ , %@", Latitude,longditute]];
            [mailViewController setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        }



    }



    else{

        NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email");
    }
}
```

my goal is: if the person is outside the area, i want to display a UIAlert informing the user they are outside the area. If the person is inside the area, it will go through the email set up.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far before requesting an example.

Comment: @ElTomato code has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the CLLocationManager, and methods like startMonitoringForRegion:, which uses CLCircularRegion objects to define geographic regions.

If you look in the Xcode docs for startMonitoringForRegion, it has a link to a demo project called "Regions", which should get you started.